# New post - Viewed 2 times

Tags: discussion, bug

I have this question that's been puzzling me :)

When I create a new post, and I submit it, it redirects me to the post, and It says (obviously) that the question has been viewed 1 time (by me i guess). Instant reload of the page and the counter has gone up to 2. Either some moderator is light-speed fast every time or I am missing something, or it's a minor bug. Any ideas?

Comment: Didn't you know?  The spirit of Drupal itself subscribes to the site, reading every post exactly 0.00001 ms after it is added...

Comment: What? :o Is that for real? We must warn the world!

Comment: @Patrick We need to teach that spirit to flag crappy questions...

Comment: Why is it crappy? It's a valid question. Maybe not important but if you have any insight you should enlighten me instead of being sarcastic. Noted that it doesn't affect the site's functionality in any way but still, a question is a question.

Comment: @magtak Apologies, that was in no way directed at you or any of your questions. It was a general pun about the low quality of questions we've been getting on the main site recently. I could probably have made that a bit clearer :) I've noticed strange things happening before with post views too but I'm afraid I don't know why

Comment: Well, apologies back to you then Clive. Guess I was having a mild paranoia moment there :$

Comment: Hmm I have noticed this on SO also, @PatrickKenny you are talking about Community User right ? Is there any such user on SO site ?

Comment: @2-Stroker No, I actually have no idea why this occurs.  So, just like when I'm debugging and cannot find the solution, I blame the spirit of Drupal...